# How can I stop the output from Snap SVG Animator from looping?

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe, snap.svg

I've used Animate CC with the Snap SVG Animator plugin to generate an animated SVG, but can't seem to find anything in the docs to stop the animation from automatically playing and automatically looping.

I would have thought these would have been options that would be passed into the `SVGAnim(json, width, height, fps)` object.

Currently I can somewhat solve the issue of autoplaying by calling `stop()` on the root movie clip located on the instance of `SVGAnim` straight after initialising the object.

For example: `_anim.mc.stop()`

Letting it start in the first place and then having to stop it doesn't feel like best practice.